# Add an index in an object in order to loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

Problem : I am getting a JSON file i am converting that to an object and looping it in for loop.
But in case of single data i am getting the below:
Eg 1 : Single Data
 `{     "Id": 2140,     “EmpId” : 4732,     “Flag”: "No"   }`

Eg 2 : For Multiple Data i am getting the below:
`{ "0":  {     "Id": 2140,     “EmpId” : 4732,     “Flag”: "No"   }, "1":  {     "Id": 2141,     “EmpId” : 4712,     “Flag”: “Yes”   } }`

When i try to loop that in for loop i get it as undefined for single data ie for Eg 1, for multiple data ie Eg 2 it works fine.

```
 const a = Object.values(data).length;
    console.log(a);
    for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      const res = data[i];
}
```

Using below code to convert it into JSON

```
const data = JSON.parse(message.messageText);
```

How can i handle it in this for loop or how can i make the single data into the below format

`{ "0":  {     "Id": 2140,     “EmpId” : 4732,     “Flag”: "No"   }}`

so that it reads the 0 and loops

even tried using object.entries but it reads the id as one and empid as second and so on.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You

I tried

```
const a = object.entries(data)
```

But it reads the id as one and empid as second and so on.

Comment: Can you clarify this more like a unit test, with a function? `f(input) => output`

Comment: `“EmpId”` is not valid JSON.  `U+201C : LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` and `U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` are not the right quotes to use.  You should use `"` which is `U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```js
const data = JSON.parse(message.messageText);`
```

to this:

```js
const parsed = JSON.parse(message.messageText);
const data = parsed[0] ? parsed : { 0: parsed };
```

With this, you check whether if the item `0` exists in the parsed data and just create it if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check whether `0` key exists in the data that you're receiving. If it exists, that means, you can do your normal loop.

Otherwise, you can add a `0` key, and the value will be what you receive in the input.

```js
function read(data){
  if(data?.[0]){
     const a = Object.values(data).length;    
     for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
       const res = data[i]
     }
  } else{
    const tempData = {}
    tempData[0] = data
    console.log(tempData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data={ "0":  {     "Id": 2140,     "EmpId" : 4732,     "Flag": "No"   }, "1":  {     "Id": 2141,     "EmpId" : 4712,     "Flag": "Yes"   } }

const a = Object.values(data).length;
console.log(a);

Object.keys(data).forEach((k, i) => { 
   console.log(i, data[k]);
});
```